# Duplicate a DB file[Android]

Tags: android

I'm working with an application that has to download a huge amount of data and insert them to database . I had it to work on a thread . But the problem is , when the thread is doing inserts , a db lock error occurs while my application reads from db . So I'm thinking about a way to avoid this : Copy the existing db file , let a thread to do inserts to this duplicate while my application reads from the original one until the inserts are completed . Then delete the original one and rename the duplicate to the original . My question is , is my way feasible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem during my last application development.
I ended up using ContentProviders. Use ContentProvider, this will solve your problem.

Comment: But I don't want to share the data to other applications .

Comment: add this to your manifest file if your don't want to share your data: android:exported="false". I was myself reluctant to use Content Providers at first because I didn't want to share it with other applications. But the database locked wouldn't get away despite trying different work around.

Comment: If I use Content Provider , do I have to give up the way of using SQLite database ? @Lazy Ninja

Comment: I don't know how you designed your database, but if you have used a Helper, you can re-use it. But for query, insert, delete, update data you have to implement that. Seems intimidating at first, re-writing the way to handle the database, but it is not a big deal if you know how to use the providers. What I did is to implement the Content Providers little by little. First I wrote the query part for one table, tested it , then insert() part and so on.

Comment: Have you tried a single connection ? Here http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/24474750219/single-sqlite-connection    I tried but didn't work for me.

Comment: I'm doing writes , reads in a single connection ... Didn't work for me too .